# NDK, C: Fatal signal 6 when used function - int close(int fd);

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Any variants , why after using function close(cxt->sysfs.dir_fd) (in this case cxt->sysfs.dir_fd = 0) I get error

```
04-08 13:34:57.496    4766-4782/pro.org A/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to create context, error = EGL_BAD_ALLOC
04-08 13:34:57.496    4766-4782/pro.org A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4782 (RenderThread)
```

close(cxt->sysfs.dir_fd) also = 0 , but app was crashed...
What I can do that prevent error, any debug ? In what direction to look?
Thank you

Comment: What was 0 ? The close argument, the return value, or both ? I'm not used to code with Android, but if you closed something that you didn't open yourself, as 0 (wich is the first thing that you program opened), bad things shall happen...

Comment: Could you explain why you tried to close cxt->sysfs.dir_fd ? It looks like it was something important : OpenGL probably needed that thing for rendering.

Answer (score 4):

You closed a primary ressource for OpenGL. You have to not close this ressource except if you are closing your application.

In all examples that you put in your commentaries, close was called only at the application end. You should do the same.

Comment: @Andreyua - whatever it is you are trying to do, you are going about it wrong.  Don't try to close that, at least not in the middle of your program.

Comment: @Andreyua - In most of cases, not only OpenGL, when you start an application with already some fd opened in your API, don't close them until the end of the application. If later you create your own fd by opening something else, just be sure to make them differents from those that were here before you.

Comment: @Andreyua - There is no real "check" possible by code here. It is the developer's job to be careful to not close important ressources. I suggest you to spend more time reading your API documentation : this kind of things should be warned about.

Comment: @Andreyua - I don't understand why you are so obsessed by this fd... You don't have to change it - that could even be dangerous if OpenGL try to re-use it after. The only thing to do is to not close except in your deinit function.